# Autocomplete with typeahead in rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I'm developing autocomplete for a particular form in my rails app; for this purpose I'm using typeahead.js with custom controller method. So far, it works but I need using those values within the form again so that I can press the submit button and the form will be posted and processed by rails normally. How can I do this? Here's the code right now

```
.page-header
  %h1
    = @org.name
    %small= t('.title')
= form_for @org_admin, |
       url: organization_organization_admins_path(@organization) do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.label t('.user')
    = f.hidden_field :user, id: 'user_id'
    %input.typeahead{ :type => "text", :autocomplete => "off"}
= f.submit t('.submit'), class: 'btn btn-primary'
= link_to t('.back'), organization_organization_admins_path(@organization)
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'names',
    remote: "#{search_organization_organization_admins_path(@organization)}?term=%QUERY",
    engine: Hogan,
    template: '<p><strong>{{username}}</strong></p>',
    limit: 10
    }).on('typeahead:selected', function(e, data){
        $('#user_id').value = data.id
    });
  });
```

So, I would like to populate the :user attribute in the form with the json object returned by the controller

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured out... the above code is in the right path, except for the call to this line

```
$('#user_id').value = data.id
```

Since I'm using jQuery to select the hidden element I had to use the jQuery val function instead

```
$('#user_id').val(data.id)
```